# ItemsControl with multiple ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, triggers, contenttemplate, contenttemplateselector

I have this ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer">
  <ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource myItemtemplateSelector}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource myItemsPanel}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I fill the `ItemsControl` with a class that has one boolean parameter. When it's true I want to call one `ItemTemplateSelector`; and another one in the false case.

I'm trying something like that:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource myItemsPanel}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myBoolean}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource SubdisciplineDataTemplateSelector}" />
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=myBoolean}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource SubdisciplineDataTemplateSelector2}" />
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
      </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: I might try `<Setter TargetName="myItemsControl" Property="ContentTemplate" ...`. But really, I'd just merge the two item template selectors into one that that looks at the value of the `myBoolean` in addition to whatever else. I'd also use .NET naming conventions, of course. If you're reusing those two itemtemplate selectors and you'd rather keep them distinct, there are many simple ways to reuse code in C# that don't involve any XAML gymnastics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, this line is wrong:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource SubdisciplineDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

You're trying to assign a `DataTemplateSelector` to a `DataTemplate` property.

Now, there can be many ways to achieve what you want. I would create a third `TemplateSelector`, embedding the first two as private properties.

Pretend that your class is something like this:

```
public class MyClass { public bool MyBoolean { get; set; } }
```

The `TemplateSelector` would be like this:

```
public class ThirdSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    private DataTemplateSelector _selector1 = new SubdisciplineDataTemplateSelector();
    private DataTemplateSelector _selector2 = new SubdisciplineDataTemplateSelector2();

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var obj = item as MyClass;

        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        if (obj.MyBoolean)
            return _selector1.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        else
            return _selector2.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

This in case you want/must preserve the first two selectors. If you can get rid of them, delete them and bring all the logic to the new one.

This is a general solution, maybe if you share more of your code and domain objects, there can be an even more suitable one for your case.